# access_log are not going to correct files in wildfly 8.1 server

Tags: server, wildfly, wildfly-8

We have two web applications deployed (named A and B) on the same application server (WildFly 8.1) with configuration shown below.

We have the same access-log configuration for both hosts.
Now the problem is that WildFly either logs application A in access_log.log or it logs application B in access_log.log, but not both.

If the application A logs are getting logged in access_log.log, then WildFly picks the access log from the previous day (e.g. access_log.2018-23-09.log) for application B.
And even when both applications are writing to access_log.log, the timestamps are not sorted properly.

**Below is the host configuration**

```
<host name="default-host" alias="b.xyz.com">
 <access-log pattern="%{i,X-Forwarded-For} %l %u [%t] %D &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot;"/>
</host>
<host name="ui-host" alias="a.xyz.com" default-web-module="ui-server.war">
  <access-log pattern="%{i,X-Forwarded-For} %l %u [%t] %D &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot;"/>
</host>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by giving using the prefix attribute within access_log tag.
I gave different prefix values to different host which are there in the wildfly and now they are writing to different files which seems to have solve the problem.